# Is there an icon pack for nautilus right click menu?

Tags: nautilus, menu, icons

I saw in default gnome theme icons when I clicked right the mouse. The icons are very useful for orientation in the menu.
See the picture below. How can I add some icons to standard ubuntu theme?

If there no icon pack how can I add my own icons?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. Mine *do* show up. I wonder what's up with this.

Comment: @Clay are you using < 9.04?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable this option (It's disabled by default) in the configuration manager. This should be available through Applications -> System Tools -> Configuration Manager (The System Tools menu may be hidden - you can make it visible by going to System -> Preferences -> Main Menu and selecting the checkbox next to System Tools, and possibly the one next to Configuration Editor in side the System Tools menu). Alternatively you can run `gconf-tool` from the command line.

You'll need to navigate to desktop -> gnome -> interface

[image]

Select `menus_have_icons` and check the box.

If you want the quick one liner you can enter the following in your terminal

```
gconftool --set --type bool /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons 0
```

This is the outcome

[image]

Comment: I think you mean gconf-editor instead of gconf-tool.

Comment: any updates on this? - old question, old answer, but the problem is there in 14.04 unity

Answer (score 1):

See [comment 4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/974915/comments/4) for bug 974915 "Nautilus Context menu missing icons".

Sebastien Bacher wrote on 2012-04-06:

> icons for most components got turned off like 2 years ago, they are only there in menu for objects like applications or directories, not for actions etc

Sebastien Bacher wrote on 2012-04-09:

> it's not a bug, it's a design decision

But [**the following tip**](http://vazhavandan.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/gnome-shell-context-menu-appearing.html) works!

1. Execute `Alt+F2` → run *gnome-tweak-tool*
2. Navigate to "Theme" settings
3. Enable icons in Context menus using the **sliders** "Menus Have Icons" and "Buttons Have Icons"
4. Restsart Gnome Shell doing `Alt+F2` → *r*

Answer (score 1):

**For ubuntu 12.04 to 15.04+**

To enable menu have icons, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
```

To enable button have icons, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
```

To do it graphically install `dconf-editor` or `dconf-tools`

[source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ubuntu-unity-menu-button-have-icons/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add your own icons. I suppose you would need to create your own theme. But just to add on what everyone has been saying (how to turn on the icons in menu), there is my input...

If you use "Cinnamon" desktop, you can use **cinnamon-settings**

Go to *Appearance > **Themes***

Tab *Settings*

*Miscellaneous options*

- *Show icons in menus*
- *Show icons on buttons* (you might want that one as well)