# Context menu icons in Nautilus 3.10.1?

Tags: 14.04, unity, nautilus, icons, context-menu

Not having context menu icons in Nautilus 3.10 makes it a bit more difficult to identify and remember the position of options.

[image]

How to enable them?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are one of the Gnome3 ppa victims. It happens when you upgrade your system with gnome3 ppa. 
In my case following command brought back menu icons.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 20.04 running GNOME Shell 3.36.7.

Comment: @LUser I don't know why. Do you use X server or Wayland? Your window manager is Gnome Shell, it may have its own settings. Please open a new thread. You will attract more attention and probably have  a solution in a new thread.

Comment: X server it is. I also noticed that most applications do display menu icons. But some, including the nautilus file manager, do not.

Comment: Read the following thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/15960/is-there-an-icon-pack-for-nautilus-right-click-menu; `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true` may work.

Comment: That is what I did. Although the 'buttons-have-icons' value is deprecated in Ubuntu 20.04. So I am really scratching my head here... Wondering whether the inability of e.g. nautilus to display menu icons was simply due to missing icon files, also also tried other icon themes - but to no avail.

Comment: @LUser Please read this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095662/missing-all-the-small-icons-on-submenus-in-ubuntu-18-10-gnome-3-30 It is a design issue, we can't do anything about it. Try `abhijit` answer as a last chance.