# Missing all the small icons on submenus in Ubuntu 18.10 GNOME 3.30

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

I have noticed that in my Ubuntu 18.10/GNOME 3.30.1 it is missing all the small icons that should be on the left side of the application submenus.

This problem occurs in all installed software. Even those that are installed together with Ubuntu. The following screenshot shows a submenu where the icons are missing.

[image]

Applications work flawlessly, but the absence of these little icons slows the understanding of complex application functions a bit. Any help?

Comment: This https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/ may help you, but essentally such icons are deprecated in Gnome 3.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved thanks to your post!

Comment: @Fabro, would be good if you write an answer and also accept it for future reference of this site of readers with the same problem. It is perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @vanadium, I was able to fix this problem by following the instructions as follows.

From the accepted answer in [this link](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23116/how-to-fix-missing-icons-in-program-menus-and-context-menus/):

> Both gtk-menu-image and gtk-button-images were deprecated and ignored, after that they made them deprecated but not ignored: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=627a03683f5f41efbfc86cc0f10e1b7c11e9bb25 https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/?id=c46aca463a9d66cf402ec8c3f9f2e2efc98c42ca
>
> the problem is the gsettings keys (org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons and menus-have-icons) are gone so I don't see a way to set them...
>
> However it seems you can set the relevant GtkSettings via the gnome-settings-daemon xsettings plguin: open dconf-editor -> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings and change the **overrides** key from:
>
> ```
> {}
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> {'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}
> ```
>
> usually the change is instantaneous (e.g. in gimp), but some apps need to be restarted (e.g. firefox).
>
> Or just use gsettings:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
> ```
>
> but note that this method overwrites the current value of that key; one obvious caveat is if you've previously enabled pasting with the middle click from gnome-tweak-tool -> "keyboard and mouse", you'll need to re-set it there again (unlike the above gsettings command, gnome-tweak-tool "adds" new values to the overrides key and doesn't blindly overwrite it).
>
> Edit: testing recently, it seems now that toggling either of these settings in gnome-tweak-tool remove the custom values added above:
>
> - Top Bar -> "show application menu"
> - Keyboard and mouse -> middle-click paste so if you toggle any of those settings you'll have to re-add the **'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>**, **'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>** bits.

Answer (score 0):

These icons are deprecated. Fortunately, Kicad has [an FAQ on how to enable them](https://answers.launchpad.net/kicad/+question/269770):

In the terminal, do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
```

(To disable them again, run the same commands, but replace `true` with `false`.)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried these commands, but nothing changed. I think it's really a Gnome incompatibility with these icons.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in Fedora 30 with KDE Plasma.
Solved the problem by going to:

*System settings → Application Style → Gnome/GTK Application Style → Behaviour*

Enabled: "Show icons in GTK buttons" and "Show icons in GTK menues"